# Complexity of solving a linear system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, computational-complexity, numerical-linear-algebra

I am analyzing the run time of an algorithm that depends on finding a solution to the linear system $A x = b$ where $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix and need to know the run time complexity of this operation.

If $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix the linear system of equations $A x = b$ can be solved by calling a matrix multiplication algorithm. The Coppersmith-Winograd algorithm multiplies two $n \times n$ matrices in $O(n^{2.375477})$ time. However, I'm assuming more goes into solving the linear system than just a call to this algorithm. What is the complexity of solving a linear system using this implementation? Can we get a similar run time complexity for $m \times n$ matrices?

Comment: You need the Gaussian Elimination to solve that not Matrix Multiplication.

Comment: It's my understanding that a linear system can be solved more efficiently using methods other than Gaussian elimination. I think I found the answer to my question in this paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0196677482900074 which shows how to solve a linear system in $O(m^{\alpha - 1} n)$, where $\alpha$ is the complexity of matrix multiplication, by computing an LSP decomposition.

Comment: If you want to go research level, Maybe it is better to ask at Math Overflow. There are similar questions over there.

Comment: Matrix inversion has the [same complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Blockwise_inversion) as matrix matrix products, so the algorithmic complexity of a linear solve is also the same.